# least upper bound for rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

In proofs for incompleteness of rational numbers

In demonstrating the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ are incomplete the following example is most often used.

Let $S$ is the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2<2$.

The proof goes something like this.

The least upper bound is $\sqrt 2$ and you can show that $\sqrt 2$ is not rational, therefore the rationals $\Bbb Q$ for this set does not exist.

I’ve seen this explanation dozens of times.

My problem is this:

A supremum does not have to be in the set $S$. So, any rational number $> \
\sqrt2~$ is an upper bound e.g. $ 3, 50$ and $1000$. Since we assume no rational numbers exist (yet), the set of upper bounds consists of only rational numbers.  So, we must prove it is impossible to find a least upper bound that is a rational number.  In effect Suppose $A$ is the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2<2$ and $B$ is the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2>2$. We want to show that $B$ contains no smallest rational number.

Comment: Please use mathjax for typesetting math. I did some for you. Click the edit button and finish the rest.

Comment: You are absolutely right; the explanation that you have seen dozens of times is logically invalid. We do indeed have to show that $B$ contains no smallest rational number. (But to make this work, you have to define $B$ as the set of all rationals $p$ such that $p^2\ge 2$, not $p^2>2$; otherwise you could modify the proof to show that $\sqrt 4$ is irrational.)

Comment: Because the rationals are dense in the reals , for every rational number $r<\sqrt{2}$ there is a rational number $s$ with $r<s<\sqrt{2}$ , and analogue for every rational number $s>\sqrt{2}$ there is a rational number $r$ with $\sqrt{2}<r<s$. Therefore neither the infimum nor the supremum exists.

Comment: @Peter, I think you are missing the point. What if $r=\sqrt 2$? Then there is no such $s$! And you can't come back at me with "But I said $r$ was rational!", because the irrationality of $r$ is just what we are trying to prove.

Comment: @TonyK You can just construct the reals first and use it to prove this theorem.

Comment: @TonyK In fact, I assumed that we use the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ to prove the non-existence of infimum and supremum.

Comment: @aristotlefromgreece, the incompleteness of the rationals comes logically _before_ the construction of the reals. I think the OP has a small typo: "Since we assume no rational numbers exist" should read "Since we assume no _irrational_ numbers exist."

Comment: I am confused as to why there is a problem.  Assume a is least upper bound for A and a is rational.  Since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, a$\lt \sqrt{2}$ so there exists a rational number c, in the interval between a and $\sqrt{2}$ contradicting assumption that a is an upper bound.

Comment: @Peter, see my reply to aristotlefromgreece's comment. I think the OP wants to prove the _non-existence_ of $\sqrt 2$ in the rationals. without first having to construct the reals. jsp55, this is a worthy goal; don't take all these comments seriously.

Comment: The question does not state that we must prove , apart from the incompleteness of $\mathbb R$ , also (at the same time) the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. And there is a simple proof of this fact that does not need the construction of the real numbers.

Comment: It's not required to show that $p^2 > 2$ has no greatest lower bound if you've already proved that $p^2 < 2$ has no least upper bound. This is because it's necessary for both the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound to be in the set for it to be complete, so it's sufficient to show one of them fails.

Comment: @Peter et al, I've tried to explain it as simply as I can. It is not difficult to prove from within the rationals that $\Bbb Q$
is incomplete, by showing that the set $\{p\in\Bbb Q:p^2<2\}$ has no least upper bound; the real numbers, and in particular the purported $\sqrt 2$, don't need to play any role in this at all. The OP is asking, quite rightly, why this approach is not used more often. It is indeed more logical.

Comment: How is one supposed to prove "$\sqrt{2}$" has no least upper bound if they have not constructed the reals? Is this the point you are trying to make?

Comment: @aristotlefromgreece, as I said in my latest comment: it is easy to prove that the set $\{p\in\Bbb Q\;:\:p^2<2\}$ has no least upper bound, without having to construct the reals. Hence $\Bbb Q$ is incomplete. There is no need to mention $\sqrt 2$ at all.

Comment: @TonyK : fully agree with your comments! The fact that rationals have some deficiency needs to be demonstrated without showing the power of a superior system $\mathbb{R} $. Moreover such an approach (remaining within rationals) gives the motivation to build something new and more powerful which has the desired least upper bound property.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution to my own question.

Some of the commenters may have misunderstood the question. It's not about proving that $\sqrt{2}$  is irrational. That's easy enough. We know $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for any *p* that is prime. Since $2$ is prime then $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

However, the question is how to show the rationals do not satisfy the **Axiom of Completeness** (AoC). That is, how to show that for any bounded finite set of rationals *S* there is no least upper bound *sup S* in the rationals.

*Solution*

Try to find a counter example. Consider $\sqrt{2}$ as a cut that splits the rational numbers *Q* into two sets *A* and *B*. *A* is the set of rationals to the left and *B* is the set of rationals to the right. This is a **Dedekind** cut.

Consider set *A* as consisting of the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$,

*A* = {a1 , a2, a3 ... } = {1.4, 1.41, 1.414, 1.4142, 1.41421, ... }.

These are strictly rational numbers $a_i\in Q$. The terms $a_i$ get as close to $\sqrt{2}$ as we like but we can never reach it, there is always another rational closer. This is consistent with the rules for the Dedekind cut.

Next is the part I am trying to prove. Here is my attempt:

We need to show that the set $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,...\}$ does not have a least element or LUB. To do this, let's take set *A* and add to each element a positive rational number $e_i$ so that each $b_i$ = $a_i+e_i$ is greater than $\sqrt{2}$. In other words $B=\{b1,b2,b3,...\} = \{a1+e1, a2+e2 ... \}$.

The terms $a_i$ get as close to $\sqrt{2}$ as we like. Choose $ei$ such that each $b_i$ is greater than $\sqrt{2}$. Then the magnitude of $e_i$ required to keep $b_i=a_i+e_i > \sqrt{2}$ gets arbirarily small. Now we need to ask, is there a least element in *B* they would prevent us from making $e_i$ as small as we like.

The answer is no since the rationals are densely packed. That is, no matter how small we make $e_i$, you can always find a smaller rational number $e_i'$ between $0$ and $e_i$. This means there is no lower bound for the set *B*. QED

Not sure if I proved it correctly?